# Create a new table in sql server migration studio with the table structure of oracle server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to create a setup in order to move tables dynamically from Oracle to SQL and one of the steps in that process requires me to create a duplicate of the table in Oracle in SQL and I'm not able to figure how to utilize the Oracle table schema to create the table in SQL
Following is the code I use to setup the schema but don't know how to convert it:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=w80426.DANSKENET.NET)(PORT=1521))"
              +"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=FRSYS)));"
              +"User Id = "+ inst +"; Password = "+ inst +"; ";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
DataTable dtTables = conn.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { "LDM_FIA", "RECS_TYPE_1000", null });
int columnIndex = 2;
int columnIndex1 = 4;
int columnIndex2 = 5;
string forQuery ="";
int i = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in dtTables.Rows)
{
  if (i < dtTables.Rows.Count)
  {
   forQuery = forQuery + row[columnIndex].ToString() + " " + row[columnIndex1].ToString()
   + "(" + row[columnIndex2].ToString() + ") NULL,";
  }
  else {
         forQuery = forQuery + row[columnIndex].ToString() + " " + row[columnIndex1].ToString()
                     + "(" + row[columnIndex2].ToString() + ") NULL";
       }
            i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper class many years ago to help create and populate SQL Tables based on a .net DataTable object. The following SqlTableManager class might be able to help you out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace App.Sql.TableManagement
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Struct stores the schema information for a sql server table column
    /// </summary>
    public struct SqlTableColumnSchema
    {
        public string ColumnName;
        public string DataType;
        public int MaximumLength;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class is responsible for synchronizing a SQL Server table with a .net DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    public class SqlTableManager
    {
        private DataTable m_TableSchema;
        private string m_SqlConnectionString;
        private string m_SqlTableName;

        private Dictionary<string, SqlTableColumnSchema> m_SqlTableColumns = new Dictionary<string, SqlTableColumnSchema>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Class contructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="schemaFile">The xml file that contains the table schema</param>
        /// <param name="sqlConnectionString">Connection string to the destination database</param>
        /// <param name="sqlTableName">The name of the destination table if this value is null then the table in xml file will be used.</param>
        public SqlTableManager(DataTable table, string sqlConnectionString)
        {
            m_SqlConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
            m_SqlTableName = table.TableName.Replace("dbo.", "");
            m_SqlTableColumns = new Dictionary<string, SqlTableColumnSchema>();

            m_TableSchema = table;
            GetSqlTableColumns();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bulk load current datatable to SQL Server.
        /// </summary>
        public void UploadTableToSql()
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(m_SqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = m_SqlTableName;

                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(m_TableSchema);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    string errorMessage = "Failed to bulk load table to SQL.";

                    throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage, exception);
                }
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method creates destination table if table does not exists, otherwise method will alter destination table to match schema of current data table.
        /// </summary>
        public void SyncTableSchemas()
        {
            bool tableExists = DestinationTableExists();

            if (!tableExists)
            {
                CreateSqlTable();
            }
            else
            {
                // Compare sql table schema against sql server table schema
                UpdateTableSchema();
                GetSqlTableColumns();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateTableSchema()
        {
            List<SqlTableColumnSchema> missingColumns = GetMissingColumns();

            if (missingColumns.Count > 0)
            {
                string alterTableQuery = string.Format("ALTER TABLE [{0}] ", m_SqlTableName); //ADD [fredA] VARCHAR(20) NULL, [fredB] INT NULL;";

                bool isFirstColumn = true;

                string addColumnQuery = "";

                foreach (SqlTableColumnSchema missingColumn in missingColumns)
                {


                    if (isFirstColumn)
                    {
                        addColumnQuery += string.Format("ADD [{0}] {1} NULL", missingColumn.ColumnName, missingColumn.DataType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        addColumnQuery += string.Format(", [{0}] {1} NULL", missingColumn.ColumnName, missingColumn.DataType);
                    }

                    isFirstColumn = false;
                }

                alterTableQuery += addColumnQuery + ";";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(m_SqlConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.CommandText = alterTableQuery;

                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            string errorMessage = "Failed to update destination table schema. Please ensure that schema file is valid.";

                            throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage, exception);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public List<SqlTableColumnSchema> GetMissingColumns()
        {
            List<SqlTableColumnSchema> missingColumns = new List<SqlTableColumnSchema>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in m_TableSchema.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = column.ColumnName;

                bool columnExistsInTable = m_SqlTableColumns.ContainsKey(columnName);

                if (!columnExistsInTable)
                {
                    SqlTableColumnSchema newColumnSchema = new SqlTableColumnSchema();
                    newColumnSchema.ColumnName = columnName;
                    newColumnSchema.DataType = SQLGetType(column);
                    newColumnSchema.MaximumLength = 0;
                }
            }

            return missingColumns;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method is used to determine if the destination table already exists.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool DestinationTableExists()
        {
            int objectCount = 0;
            string tableName = m_SqlTableName;
            bool tableExist = false;

            string sql = "SELECT count(*) as IsExists FROM dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id('[dbo].[" + tableName + "]')";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(m_SqlConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();


                    objectCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    string errorMessage = "Failed to verify if destination table exists. Please verify that sql user account has the necessary permissions to perform this action.";

                    throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage, exception);
                }
            }

            if (objectCount > 0)
                tableExist = true;
            else
                tableExist = false;

            return tableExist;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method retrives the columns of the destination sql table
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private void GetSqlTableColumns()
        {
            string tableName = m_SqlTableName;
            string sql = string.Format("select COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName ,DATA_TYPE as DataType, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as MaximumLength FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}'", tableName);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(m_SqlConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                int columnNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");
                                int dataTypeOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("DataType");
                                int maximumLengthOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("MaximumLength");

                                string columnName = reader.GetString(columnNameOrdinal);
                                string columnDataType = reader.GetString(dataTypeOrdinal);

                                int columnLength = 0;
                                bool maxLengthColumnIsNull = reader.IsDBNull(maximumLengthOrdinal);

                                if (!maxLengthColumnIsNull) columnLength = reader.GetInt32(maximumLengthOrdinal);

                                bool columnAlreadyAdded = m_SqlTableColumns.ContainsKey(columnName);

                                if (!columnAlreadyAdded)
                                {
                                    SqlTableColumnSchema columnSchema = new SqlTableColumnSchema();
                                    columnSchema.ColumnName = columnName;
                                    columnSchema.DataType = columnDataType;
                                    columnSchema.MaximumLength = columnLength;

                                    m_SqlTableColumns.Add(columnName, columnSchema);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        string errorMessage = "Failed to retrieve if destination table’s columns. Please verify that sql user account has the necessary permissions to perform this action.";

                        throw new ApplicationException(errorMessage, exception);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method will attempt to create a new sql table based of the DataTable schema object.
        /// </summary>
        private void CreateSqlTable()
        {
            string tableName = m_SqlTableName;
            DataTable table = m_TableSchema;

            string sql = GenerateSqlScriptCreateTable(tableName, table);


            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(m_SqlConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                try
                {
                    // Create the sql table
                    using (SqlCommand createTableCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    string exceptionMessage = string.Format("CreateFromDataTable(): Failed to create sql table '{0}'", tableName);
                    throw new ApplicationException(exceptionMessage, exception);
                }

                // Add column indexes and description
                foreach (DataColumn field in table.Columns)
                {
                    string scriptAddColumnDescription = GenerateSqlScriptAddDescriptions(tableName, field);

                    if (scriptAddColumnDescription != "")
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand addColumnDescriptionCommand = new SqlCommand(scriptAddColumnDescription, connection))
                        {
                            addColumnDescriptionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to 'CreateFromDataTable'. Method will generate scripts to create the main body of destination table.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tableName"></param>
        /// <param name="table"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GenerateSqlScriptCreateTable(string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE [" + tableName + "] (\n";
            // columns
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "] " + SQLGetType(column) + ",\n";
            }
            sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',', '\n' }) + "\n";
            // primary keys
            if (table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
            {
                sql += "CONSTRAINT [PK_" + tableName + "] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (";
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.PrimaryKey)
                {
                    sql += "[" + column.ColumnName + "],";
                }
                sql = sql.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' }) + "))\n";
            }

            //if not ends with ")"
            if ((table.PrimaryKey.Length == 0) && (!sql.EndsWith(")")))
            {
                sql += ")";
            }

            return sql;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Methods returns a valid sql string representation of an input data type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type"></param>
        /// <param name="columnSize"></param>
        /// <param name="numericPrecision"></param>
        /// <param name="numericScale"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string SQLGetType(object type, int columnSize, int numericPrecision, int numericScale)
        {
            switch (type.ToString())
            {
                case "System.String":
                    return "NVARCHAR(" + ((columnSize == -1) ? "255" : (columnSize > 8000) ? "MAX" : columnSize.ToString()) + ")";

                case "System.Decimal":
                    if (numericScale > 0)
                        return "FLOAT";
                    else if (numericPrecision > 10)
                        return "BIGINT";
                    else
                        return "INT";

                case "System.Double":
                case "System.Single":
                    return "FLOAT";

                case "System.Int64":
                    return "BIGINT";

                case "System.Int16":
                case "System.Int32":
                    return "INT";

                case "System.DateTime":
                    return "DATETIME";

                case "System.Boolean":
                    return "BIT";

                case "System.Byte":
                    return "TINYINT";

                case "System.Guid":
                    return "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER";

                default:
                    throw new Exception(type.ToString() + " not implemented.");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overload based on DataColumn from DataTable type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string SQLGetType(DataColumn column)
        {
            return SQLGetType(column.DataType, column.MaxLength, 10, 2);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to 'CreateFromDataTable'. Method will generate scripts to create descriptions for the destination table's columns.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tableName"></param>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GenerateSqlScriptAddDescriptions(string tableName, DataColumn column)
        {
            string sqlScript = "";

            string description = GetFieldDescriptionFromExtendedProperties(column);

            if (description != "")
            {
                string fieldName = column.ColumnName;
                string fieldNameClean = fieldName.Replace(' ', '_');
                fieldNameClean = CleanString(fieldNameClean);

                string template = @"EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'{2}' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'{0}', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'{1}'";

                sqlScript = string.Format(template, tableName, fieldName, description);
            }

            return sqlScript;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method used to get the description of the 'Ampla' the data column.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column">The column in the schema data table to get the field description for</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetFieldDescriptionFromExtendedProperties(DataColumn column)
        {
            string description = "";

            bool columnHasFieldDescription = column.ExtendedProperties.Contains("Description");
            if (columnHasFieldDescription)
            {
                description = column.ExtendedProperties["Description"].ToString();
            }

            return description;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method used to clean strings from any invalid values.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string CleanString(string inputString)
        {
            // Replace invalid characters with empty strings. 
            try
            {
                return Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[^\w]", "", RegexOptions.None);
            }
            // If we timeout when replacing invalid characters,  
            // we should return Empty. 
            catch
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determine if column name is valid. The column has to exist in both the SQL Table and Schema file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool ColumnIsValid(string columnName)
        {
            bool columnExistInSchema = m_TableSchema.Columns.Contains(columnName);
            bool columnExistInDestinationTable = m_SqlTableColumns.ContainsKey(columnName);

            return (columnExistInSchema && columnExistInDestinationTable);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the data type of the column in question
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="columnName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Type GetColumnType(string columnName)
        {
            return m_TableSchema.Columns[columnName].DataType;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that you can simply fill a DataTable with data from Oracle. The SqlTableManager class can then create SQL table from the DataTable object and if you so choose bulk load the source data into the newly created table. The above class can be used as follow:

```
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Your Oracle Connection string");

        Conn.Open;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("your select table query");

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
        {
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }


        foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
        {

            SqlTableManager tableManager = new SqlTableManager(table, "Your SQL Server Connection string");
            tableManager.SyncTableSchemas(); // Create or update the SQL Server table.
            tableManager.UploadTableToSql(); // Bulk load DataTable into the newly created table.
        }
```